# Post a tweet to my feed using Google Apps Script

Tags: twitter, google-apps-script, twitter-oauth

As the title suggests, my goal here is to be able to send a tweet from a `script.gs`. The tweet would be posted to my feed, ideally without me having to visit the Twitter website.

I wrote two main functions to attempt this:

script.gs

```
//post tweet
function oAuth() {
  var CONSUMER_KEY = "**********************";
  var CONSUMER_SECRET = "*************************************************";
  ScriptProperties.setProperty("TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY", CONSUMER_KEY);
  ScriptProperties.setProperty("TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET", CONSUMER_SECRET);
  var oauthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService("twitter");
  oauthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token");
  oauthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token");
  oauthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize");
  oauthConfig.setConsumerKey(ScriptProperties.getProperty("TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY"));
  oauthConfig.setConsumerSecret(ScriptProperties.getProperty("TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET"));
  var options = {muteHttpExceptions: true,oAuthServiceName:'twitter',oAuthUseToken:'always'}
  var url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getContentText();
  Logger.log(response);
}
function postTweet() {
  oAuth();
  Logger.log('oAuth complete');
  var status = "Tweet";
  var Roptions = {
    method: "post",
    oAuthServiceName: "twitter",
    oAuthUseToken: "always",
    status: status
  };
  var url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json";
  Logger.log('begin post');
  var request = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, Roptions); //the trouble line. Execution stops.
  Logger.log('post complete');
}
```

After about a day of relentless hacking, I was able to get the first function, `oAuth()` to work. That logs, well, my user data. However, for the life of me, I cannot figure out what is holding up `request`. I do get this error: `Request failed for returned code 403. Truncated server response: {"errors":[{"message":"SSL is required","code":92}]}`. Googling this didn't turn up much. I'm guessing that the issue is somewhere in `Roptions`. Any help would be appreciated, and I can try to provide further clarification if needed.

Comment: SSL is synonymous with HTTPS.  Your `url` variable uses HTTP and not HTTPS.   I'd try that as the simplest first step.  `var url = "https://api.twitter.etc`

Comment: The Twitter API Documentation uses HTTPS.  [Tweet API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update)

Comment: *facepalm* for missing the https. However, I now get the error `Request failed for returned code 403. Truncated server response: {"errors":[{"code":170,"message":"Missing required parameter: status."}]}`. But I have `status` in `Roptions`??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eureka! Here's the solution. The irony is that I had had something like this before, but had dismissed it. Turns out `https` was my biggest problem. I'll feast on humble pie tonight.

script to send tweet

```
//post tweet
function oAuth() {
  var CONSUMER_KEY = "*************************";
  var CONSUMER_SECRET = "**************************************************";
  ScriptProperties.setProperty("TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY", CONSUMER_KEY);
  ScriptProperties.setProperty("TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET", CONSUMER_SECRET);
  var oauthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService("twitter");
  oauthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token");
  oauthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token");
  oauthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate");
  oauthConfig.setConsumerKey(ScriptProperties.getProperty("TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY"));
  oauthConfig.setConsumerSecret(ScriptProperties.getProperty("TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET"));
  var options = {muteHttpExceptions: true,oAuthServiceName:'twitter',oAuthUseToken:'always'}
  var url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getContentText();
  Logger.log(response);
}
function postTweet() {
  oAuth();
  Logger.log('oAuth complete');
  var status='Test tweet';
  var options = {
    "method": "post",
    "oAuthServiceName": "twitter",
    "oAuthUseToken": "always",
    "payload":{"status":status}
  };
  var url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json";
  Logger.log('begin post');
  var request = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log('post complete');
}
```

When you register your Twitter app, you have to check the option `Allow this application to be used to Sign in with Twitter`. This prevents continual Authorize popups. Also, the tweet text CANNOT contain single quotes (`'`).

Comment: This solution is deprecated https://cloud.google.com/blog/changes-oauth-apps-script

Answer (score 1):

@J148, oauthConfig depricated and you can't use it anymore;

Now for twitter you have to use OAuth1 for Apps Script. Migration docs:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/migration/oauth-config?utm_campaign=oauth-appsscript-315&utm_source=gadbc&utm_medium=blog

Sample:
https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth1/blob/master/samples/Twitter.gs

To make sample working you have to:

- Add "OAuth1 for Apps Script library" to your script project
- Declare some stub "Callback URL" in the twitter app's settings