# Create new tweet with Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, twitter

(I have read already the solution given in [Tweet using Google Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25982488/tweet-using-google-script) but it doesn't work for me. Please don't delete this question.)

**Page** https://ctrlq.org/code/19995-google-script-to-twitter shows a way to create a tweet in Google Script.
I simply pasted the code offered there and successfully followed this instructions:

1. Go to apps.twitter.com and create a new app
2. Generate Access Token and Secret
3. Include Twitter library key «MKvHYYdYA4G5JJHj7hxIcoh8V4oX7X1M_» in Google Script
4. Activate «Enable Sign in with Twitter» in «App details» in Twitter
5. Add the «Callbacks URL» in Twitter using my Google Script Project Key: https://script.google.com/macros/d/ML3pMd5z.../usercallback

**Now**, when I run the code almost nothing happens, but this error message: **`ReferenceError: "twit" is not defined. (line 22, file "Code")`**.

```
function sendTweet(status){

status = status || "I found this snippet on @labnol's ctrlq.org";

var twitterKeys= {
TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY: "1fZn8cBR...",
TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET: "588gJxh...",
TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN: "112c5e0...",
TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET: "DcvV614.",
};

var props = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();

props.setProperties(twitterKeys);

var service = new Twitter.OAuth(props);

if ( service.hasAccess() ) {

var response = twit.sendTweet(status); // ← THIS IS LINE 21

if (response) {
  Logger.log("Tweet ID " + response.id_str);
} else {
  // Tweet could not be sent
  // Go to View -> Logs to see the error message
    }
  }  
}
```

Please tell me how to fix ***this specific code***.

---

Found the answer in https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/i-made-a-twitter-bot-from-nothing-but-a-google-sheet-ef0ba6e1b194 and simply added the missing variable after **`var service = new Twitter.OAuth(props);`**:

```
var twit = new Twitter.OAuth(props);
```

The final code is like so:

```
function sendTweet(){
  var status = "Text to be tweeted goes here.";
  var twitterKeys= {
    TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY: "1fZBR...",
    TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET: "Ig...tzpa4E...",
    TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN: "1125...90...",
    TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET: "...22GrDcv...",
    };
  var props = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  props.setProperties(twitterKeys);
  var service = new Twitter.OAuth(props);
  var twit = new Twitter.OAuth(props); // ← THIS WAS THE MISSING VARIABLE
  if ( service.hasAccess() ) {
    var response = twit.sendTweet(status);
      if (response) {
        Logger.log("Tweet ID " + response.id_str);
        } else { }
     }  
  }
```

Comment: Is this thread useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/34668592/7108653